# Serverless | How to connect a Lambda function as trigger to a DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I'm trying to connect a Lambda function as a trigger for a DynamoDB table.

In my serverless.yml file, I have defined a Lambda function and a DynamoDB table.

**Question:** How can I attach the Lambda function as a trigger to the DynamoDB?

My `serverless.yaml` (simplified):

```
functions:
  pushLeadEvent:
    handler: handler.pushLeadEvent
    events:
      - /* WHAT TO DO HERE? */

resources:
  Resources:
    leadEvent:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: leadEvent
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: owner
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: timestamp
            AttributeType: N
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: owner
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: timestamp
            KeyType: RANGE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [Serverless Framework documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/streams/) and my personal experience, I would recommend this:

```
functions:
  pushLeadEvent:
    handler: handler.pushLeadEvent
    dependsOn:
     - leadEvent
    events:
     - stream:
       type: dynamodb
       arn: !GetAtt leadEvent.StreamArn
       batchSize: 100
       startingPosition: LATEST
       maximumRetryAttempts: 10
       bisectBatchOnFunctionError: true
       enabled: true
```

This will:

- Subcribe your Lambda to all of the changes in `leadEvent` table.
- Single batch can have up to 100 events.
- Lambda will retry to process an event up to 10 times, if it fails
- On each retry, if batch has more than 1 event, it will be splitted into 2 separated batches by half

Comment: Thank you. I get the error: EventSourceArn.split is not a function.

Comment: Could you try adding `dependsOn:  - leadEvent ` in function definition? Just under handler definition, on the same yaml level, leadEvent should be defined as first element of list, search "dependsOn" here for better example:
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/

Comment: I got it to work. Needed to add dependsOn (as you mentioned), but also set type: dynamodb 
Thank you for your help!